# Microsoft Teams MessageCard (Connector card) doesn't display Images

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks, newrelic, payload, office365connectors

I'm testing out the Message Card type payload, but Images won't show. Am I missing something?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#example-of-an-office-365-connector-card

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTA3R.png)

```
        {
            "title": "Images",
            "images": [
                {
               "image":"http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/MicrosoftSurface_024_Cafe_OH-06315_VS_R1c.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image":"http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/WIN12_Scene_01.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "image":"http://connectorsdemo.azurewebsites.net/images/WIN12_Anthony_02.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: We are able to repro your issue. We have raised a bug for the same. We will let you know once we have any updates on it.

Comment: Sounds good. Is the bug tracker open to public?

Comment: No. The bug tracker is not open for public.

Comment: any update? any estimated date to be fixed ? @Nivedipa-MSFT

Comment: We are checking the status of the bug fix with engineering team. We will keep you posted if there are any updates.

Comment: I wonder how Microsoft Teams works, if it takes so much time just to check the status of a bug ... maybe are they working with paper yet? 
Remember (Microsoft Team) that we (the developers) are the ones promoting your tools (the ones you get money from), using your API's ... if they are not working, we move to other platforms ... this is why I prefer to use Slack or Discord integrations.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Engineering team is working on the fix. Currently we don't have any ETA to share. We will inform you if we get any updates from them.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, has there been an update on this fix?

Comment: Engineering team is working on the fix. We will update you once it is publically released.

Comment: Hello everyone, We have got an update from engineering team that the that they are not fixing Angular bug anymore as T2.1 will be GA soon on 9/30